# Почему jQuery реагирует на :hover только один раз, а потом перестает?

Tags: jquery

Вот код:

```
$('.grid1').hover(function() {
$('.grid1').css({
    '-webkit-box-shadow' : '3px 3px 3px #333'
}),
$('.grid1').hover(function() {
    $('.grid1').css({
        '-webkit-box-shadow' : '0 0 0'
    })
})
});
```

После загрузки страницы, навожу мышкой - сработало. Убрал мышку - сработало. А вот когда второй раз навожу, он никак не реагирует. С чем это связано и как исправить это?

Comment: почему-бы просто :hover в css не сделать ?

Comment: @navi1893, а вы зайти на сайт Жиквери и почитать документацию в состоянии? Вопросу — минус.

Comment: Предлагаю минуснуть пользователя artuska, он всем вопросам ставит минусы. На данный момент 26 минусов против 5 плюсов, что говорит о его страсти всё минусить.
Вы, artuska, тут что делаете? Не нравятся вопросы, не отвечайте! Вы в каждой бочке затычка! Если бы все всё читали и всё знали, то зачем было бы вообще создавать подобные сайты...

Comment: @Skolozub это его право - минусовать или нет. Земля круглая - всё вернется.

Comment: Я абсолютно адекватно минусую абсолютно дилетантские вопросы. Этот сайт наполовину помойка, вот как раз из-за таких, которые вообще не выучили ни капельки Яваскрипт или ЦСС и по каждой мелочи просят, чтобы за них решили задачу.

Comment: «Если бы все всё читали и всё знали» — да не нужно всё знать, нужно иметь элементарный интеллект чуть выше плинтуса, чтобы догадаться поискать ответ про Жиквери в документации по Жиквери! Невероятно, да?

Comment: Автору же вопроса это невдомек и он постит сюда кучи однотипных вопросов — можно посмотреть его профиль.

Comment: Но вы не утруждаете себя плюсовать хорошие вопросы. Или по вашему мнению их тут ровно пять?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Смотрим пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/DPnCS/1/) работы данного кода:

```
$('.grid1').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).css({
            'box-shadow' : '3px 3px 3px #333',
            '-webkit-box-shadow' : '3px 3px 3px #333'
        });
    },
    function() {
        $(this).css({
            'box-shadow' : '0 0 0',
            '-webkit-box-shadow' : '0 0 0'
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: @Deonis Кстати правильно вначале с префиксами писать CSS свойства, а потом - без :)